# Stop all animations in createjs Flash animation

Tags: javascript, flash, createjs

I'm using Flash CC canvas project to create a banner. Is there a way to stop all nested animations using JavaScript? I tried `createjs.Ticker.setPaused(true);` but it does nothing useful.

(I know I could recursively loop through everything and stop() it but that's not what I'm asking about :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't way to stop all the animations without looping in createjs.

createjs.Ticker.setPaused(true); -- will only pause the rendering of things on the complete stage, the animations code will continue to run in the background, so when you unpause the ticker, a sudden final state of animations will be shown which must have gotten executed by that time.

If you a specific Container that is having those animations, you can try cache() method for that particular container. Caching works like taking a snap, so the animations will not run, until you uncache().

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know it follows Flash architecture quite closely, but it's stil, a pity. AFAIK `cache()` will replace a container with a bitmap image. Does it also stop underlying animations code or just the rendering?